# How to store values about my application permanently?

Tags: android

I have an application where i need to store some data, presently i am storing it this way:

```
@Override
protected void onDestroy() {
    super.onDestroy();
    editor = preferences.edit();
    editor.putInt("DigitButtonStyle",button1);
    editor.putInt("MemoryButtonStyle", buttonmadd);
    editor.putInt("FunctionButtonStyle", buttoncos);
    editor.putString("InputTextValue",inputText.getText().toString());
    editor.commit();
}

@Override
protected void onPause() {
    super.onPause();
    editor = preferences.edit();
    editor.putInt("DigitButtonStyle",button1);
    editor.putInt("MemoryButtonStyle", buttonmadd);
    editor.putInt("FunctionButtonStyle", buttoncos);
    editor.putString("InputTextValue",inputText.getText().toString());
    editor.commit();
}
```

The data is stored and if my activity is moved to background or screen orientation is changed, it restores its state. But, if i press middle button on my device to see all running background apps and remove it from there it does not restore the data. What should i do?

It is the code i am using to write data to my preferences as it is recorded:

```
switch (item.getItemId())
    { 
      case R.id.blue:
          for (Button currentButton : buttons) {
                currentButton.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.blue);
                button1 = buttoncos = buttonmadd = R.drawable.blue;
            };
            editor.putInt("DigitButtonStyle",button1);
            editor.putInt("MemoryButtonStyle", buttonmadd);
            editor.putInt("FunctionButtonStyle", buttoncos);
                        editor.commit();
          return true;
```

But it does not work.

Given below is part of my onCreate Code:

```
public class MainActivity extends ActionBarActivity 
{

private TextView inputText,resultText,memoryStatText;
public static int button1,buttoncos,buttonmadd;


@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    ThemeChanger.onActivityCreateSetTheme(this);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);

    preferences = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(this);


for (Button currentButton : digitbuttons) {
        currentButton.setBackgroundResource(button1);
    }
  for (Button currentButton : memoryfunctions) {
        currentButton.setBackgroundResource(buttonmadd);
    }
  for (Button currentButton : functionbuttons) {
        currentButton.setBackgroundResource(buttoncos);
    }
```

Comment: Show the part of code where you read SharedPreferences.

Comment: This is all i have, i don't think i read these preferences anywhere, how can i read my preferences.I thought         preferences = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(this); did that job.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because when you killed your app by yourself,then Android OS won＇t trigger your onDestroy method,so you need to save the records at the time it is made,not in the onDestroy method.

Your lifecircle methods are ok,but if you remove the task which will tell Android OS to kill you process,storing process won´t  be triggered.So you need to store the records when they are generated.
Your code have lost the commit step:

```
switch (item.getItemId())
{ 
  case R.id.blue:
      for (Button currentButton : buttons) {
            currentButton.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.blue);
            button1 = buttoncos = buttonmadd = R.drawable.blue;
        };
        editor.putInt("DigitButtonStyle",button1);
        editor.putInt("MemoryButtonStyle", buttonmadd);
        editor.putInt("FunctionButtonStyle", buttoncos);
        editor.commit();
      return true;
```

In your `onCreate` mehod,you should check if the referenced color have been stored before.

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    ThemeChanger.onActivityCreateSetTheme(this);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);
    int defaultValue = R.drawable.blue;
    preferences = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(this);
    button1 = preferences.getInt("DigitButtonStyle",defaultValue);
    buttonmadd = preferences.getInt("MemoryButtonStyle",defaultValue);
    buttoncos = preferences.getInt("FunctionButtonStyle",defaultValue);
    for (Button currentButton : digitbuttons) {
        currentButton.setBackgroundResource(button1);
    }
    for (Button currentButton : memoryfunctions) {
        currentButton.setBackgroundResource(buttonmadd);
    }
    for (Button currentButton : functionbuttons) {
        currentButton.setBackgroundResource(buttoncos);
    }
```

Comment: No,do nothing about your lifecircle,just write record to file when the record is generated.

Comment: I am editing my question. correct me if i am wrong because i did not get the desired result.

Comment: @user3404195 you have lost the sentence editor.commit();

Comment: It did not work , i am editing my question again to include onCreate method of my application. Please tell me if anything is wrong there. Thanx.

Comment: I have included editor.commit(); now but it still does not work.

Comment: @user3404195 Are you sure this code have been excuted? Add some log or debug?

Comment: I have included code for my onCreate method if something is wrong there. Yes i am sure the code with switch statement executes perfectly.

Comment: @user3404195 So you mean when your code is executed,the DigitButtonStyle entrance does not exists in your SharedPreferences＇ xml? Or what do you mean by  "it does not work"?

Comment: I mean to say that after writing the code as you told me, if i kill my app myself and then restart it, the style i applied is lost.

Comment: @user3404195.Then I know what you have lost.You need to get information from your SharedPreference in onCreate first.I will update my answer.

Answer (score 0):

Its not a good practice to have redundancy but still to achieve your task try placing the same code in onResume() too, which will be triggered during resume of your application.
Source: [Activity Life Cycle](http://developer.android.com/training/basics/activity-lifecycle/index.html)
But you should write your program in the flow of its natural life cycle for its best practice. Not all users will interrupt the application as you are doing. I guess.

Comment: That means users will let the system kill the app when need arises.

Comment: Yes, the proper procedure to end any application is to use the "back" button of the device to end...Which will execute the onDestroy(). This is why it is said a developer should make sure to finish() an activity properly. Otherwise it will stay in the memory even if you come out of it using the "Home" button.
Refer the link I specified in my answer.

Answer (score 0):

You should always store the data that you think is essential as soon as the user triggers some action.

Do not wait for the application to be paused or killed. Just save the data as soon as user gives the input OR triggers some action. It will be the best always

Answer (score 0):

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    ThemeChanger.onActivityCreateSetTheme(this);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);

    preferences = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(this);
    button1 = preferences.getInt("DigitButtonStyle", 0);
    for (Button currentButton : digitbuttons) {
        currentButton.setBackgroundResource(button1);
    }
    buttonmadd = preferences.getInt("MemoryButtonStyle", 0);
    for (Button currentButton : memoryfunctions) {
        currentButton.setBackgroundResource(buttonmadd);
    }
    buttoncos = preferences.getInt("FunctionButtonStyle", 0);
    for (Button currentButton : functionbuttons) {
        currentButton.setBackgroundResource(buttoncos);
    }

...
}
```